# Excel - using a flag to control cell level calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to control calculation at a cell level.   Here is what I'm basically trying to do in an If statement...   I don't know how to "UseTheLastValue" of "DoThisBigLongCalc" though....

```
Cell A1 =IF(CalculateFlag = True, DoThisBigLongCalc, UseTheLastValueOfBigCalc)
```

Any help would be appreciated!   The reason I'm doing this is I have a lot of formulas that I do want to calculate every time I hit F9, but also a whole lot that I don't because of their long calc time.....  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This approach might help you,

1) Whatever cells you want to do a recalculate with `F9`, enter the formulas in the excel sheet directly. Even if you set the formula calculate method to manual, the data will be refreshed and recalculated when you press `F9`

2) For the cells which you do not want to do a recalculate, enter the formulas for those cells through `VBA`, so that whenever the code is executed, the formulas will be calculated. If not, the old value would still stay there on the cell (UseTheLastValueOfBigCalc)

This code could be triggered through a `worksheet_change` event which can detect a `True/False` on a particular cell and execute accordingly. If its true, just recalculate the formulas, if false just ignore.

Below is a code snippet which detects `True` in cell `A1` and calculates accordingly,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" And Range("A1") = True Then
        Range("B3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B1:B2"))
    End If
End Sub
```

This code sums the values in `B1` and `B2` and prints in `B3` only if `True` is entered in `A1`

[image]

Even if you change values in cells `B1` or `B2` the sum will not be recalculated, which means the old value can still be used unless `A1` is changes to `true`.

[image]

Once `True` is entered, the formulas are calculated,

[image]

Hope this helps.